# Read from Secrets Manager in AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to use the Node.js sample code that AWS Secrets Manager provides to read a secret value, and am putting this code inside a Lambda function.  However, I can't seem to get into the function that handles the response from getting the secret value.

The Lambda role has AdministratorAccess permissions to rule out it being a permissions issue.

Lambda Code:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

// Load the AWS SDK
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    region = "us-east-1",
    secretName = "/my-secrets/level1/level2",
    secret,
    decodedBinarySecret;

var client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
    region: region
});

console.log('above')

client.getSecretValue({SecretId: secretName}, function(err, data) {

    console.log('in')

    if (err) {
       throw err;
    }
    else {
        if ('SecretString' in data) {
            secret = data.SecretString;
        } else {
            let buff = new Buffer(data.SecretBinary, 'base64');
            decodedBinarySecret = buff.toString('ascii');
        }
    }

    console.log(secret)
});

console.log('below')
```

};

OUTPUT

```
2020-03-05T18:51:54.547Z    a3101875-a1f4-4b6f-ac62-3c2f93f5941f    INFO    above
2020-03-05T18:51:54.947Z    a3101875-a1f4-4b6f-ac62-3c2f93f5941f    INFO    below
```

Because the secret exists, I would expect to see "in" and the secret lines in the output...what is preventing it from getting inside that function?

Answer (score 6):

Change your call to be a promise:

```
const data = await client.getSecretValue({SecretId: secretName}).promise();
```

The problem you are running into is that the lambda is ending execution before your callback is executed. [AWS Lambda Function Handler in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html)

The above solution works, but for a full code example, please refer to this link: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/secrets/src/secrets_getsecretvalue.js